# Is it possible to use the accelerometer of Surface Pro 3 via Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, accelerometer

Is it possible to use the accelerometer of Surface Pro 3 via Qt? Will it work with QtCreator and MinGW or is Visual Studio required?

The Qt 5.3 documentation is a bit confusing to me:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtsensors-index.html

"Currently the API is supported on Android, BlackBerry 10, iOS, SailFish and WinRT"

The compatibility map (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/compatmap.html) indicates that Windows 8/RT is supported. Does this mean that Surface Pro 3 is supported?

I don't have access to a Surface Pro 3 myself so I cannot test that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible! But unfortunately not out of the box with Qt 5.4. You have to change some files in the qtsensors plugin and compile it with MSVC2013. After that you can use the sensors (including `QAccelerometer`) even from Windows 8.1 desktop (not the metro stuff).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082502/qt-5-3-cant-make-qcompass-qsensor-work-on-windows-8-1) and the answer from user2629409 which shows you the steps you need to do and my comment there when you want to know which specific sensors are available on the Surface Pro 3.

After this process you can use the qsensors just normal. Start reading on the [QSensor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsensor.html#start) class and this [overview](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsensors-cpp.html) may be a good idea.